# Two processes with the same stack pointer. Why?

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu-architecture

Using the following code to print the ESP register:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long get_sp() {
    __asm__("movl %esp, %eax");
}

int main() {
    sleep(5);
    printf("Stack pointer (ESP): 0x%x\n", get_sp());
    return 0;
}
```

Disable ASLR

```
echo "0" > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

Build:

```
gcc get_sp.c -o get_sp
```

Run two processes:

```
./get_sp & ./get_sp
```

I get:

```
Stack pointer (ESP): 0xbffff158
Stack pointer (ESP): 0xbffff158
```

I was expecting different addresses though. Can anyone shed some light on this? Is it because these are virtual memory addresses and under the hood Linux tracks memory per process and maps correctly to main memory?

Thanks

Comment: This is because every program has a 'virtual address space', not a physical one - this is what allows a page file to work, as the virtual and real physical address spaces being separated allows addresses in the program to stay the same but refer to vastly different spots (and even spots that are currently swapped out to disk). It also means that programs cannot 'clobber' each others' memories by being poorly programmed - remember windows 3.1 and windows 95, where one crashing game brought your whole computer down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it because these are virtual memory addresses and under the hood Linux tracks memory per process and maps correctly to main memory?

Yes.